# using rules to look up values

Tags: rule

I have a lookup table with about 30 rows.  Column 1 has the value I want to search for and column 2 has the value I want returned.  It seemed like I should be able to use rules to do this, but clearly I don't know what I'm doing.  Oh, the values are all strings

I tried:

```
rule2 :> (#[[1]] -> #[[2]]) & /@ elrALobMap;
```

This didn't work.  First, should I be doing this a different way? (I see that I can do it with Position and Pick, but that seemed awkward.  Second, I'd appreciate any help in understanding how (if it's possible) what I did code should be coded.

Comment: Please provide a few short sample lines of your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elrALobMap = Transpose@{ToString /@ Range@30, ToString /@ Reverse@Range@30}
rules = Dispatch[RuleDelayed @@@ elrALobMap]
"1" /. rules
(*
30
*)
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks.